# Tcl Tk double click binding is blocked by another binding

Tags: binding, tcl, selection, tk-toolkit

I work with tcl 8.6

I've got two tablelists (by Nehmeti):

```
set pfd(frMain) [frame $fr.frMain]
set pfd(bottomFr) [frame $pfd(frMain).bfr]
set pfd(panWin) [panedwindow $pfd(bottomFr).pw -showhandle 1 -orient vertical -sashpad 0 -sashrelief raised -sashwidth 2]
set pfd(frKlaffNeupkt) [frame $pfd(panWin).frKlaffNeupkt]
pack $pfd(frMesswerte)   -anchor nw -expand 0 -fill both
pack $pfd(frKlaffNeupkt) -anchor nw -expand 0 -fill both
pack $pfd(panWin) -anchor nw -expand 1 -fill both
$pfd(panWin) add $pfd(frMesswerte) $pfd(frKlaffNeupkt)
set pfd(tali_mw) [tablelist::tablelist $pfd(frMesswerte).li.tali_mw \
                  -columns {0 "oid" l \
                            0 "status" l \             
                            0 "art" l \
                            0 "sollTyp" l \
                            0 "Nr" l \
                            0 "Typ" l \
                            0 "Gst" l \
                            0 "Hz" r \
                            0 "V" r \
                            0 "S" r \
                            0 "Q" r \
                            0 "L" r \
                            0 "AK" l\
                            0 "LSEX" l \
                            0 "lfdNrGes" l}\
                  -exportselection 0 \
                  -labelbackground #EEEEEE \
                  -background white \
                  -labelfont $tableheadfont\ 
                  -font $tableinhfont\
                  -stretch 12\
                  -selectbackground $vmVConfig::setVar(activeBG) \
                  -selectforeground $vmVConfig::setVar(activeFG) \
                  -selectmode single\
                  -borderwidth 1 \
                  -labelborderwidth 1 \
                  -selectborderwidth 0 \
                  -tooltipaddcommand [::itcl::code $this tooltipAddCmd] \
                  -tooltipdelcommand [::itcl::code $this tooltipDelCmd] \
                  -xscrollcommand [list vmTkTools::configSB "h" $pfd(mw_scrx)]\
                  -yscrollcommand [list vmTkTools::configSB "v" $pfd(mw_scry)]]


set pfd(noteb) [iwidgets::notebook $pfd(frKlaffNeupkt).noteb]
pack $pfd(noteb) -anchor nw -expand 1 -fill both
set pfd(frKlaffungen) [$pfd(noteb) add -label Klaffungen]

set pfd(tali_klaff) [tablelist::tablelist $pfd(frKlaffungen).li.tali_klaff \
                      -columns {0 "oid" l 0 "Nr" l 0 "dX" r 0 "dY" r 0 "GwX" r 0 "GwY" r 0 "Rdz" r 0 "lfdNrGes" r}\
                      -exportselection 0 \
                      -labelbackground #EEEEEE \
                      -background white \
                      -labelfont $tableheadfont\
                      -font $tableinhfont\
                      -stretch 7\
                      -selectbackground $vmVConfig::setVar(activeBG) \
                      -selectforeground $vmVConfig::setVar(activeFG) \
                      -selectmode single\
                      -labelrelief groove \
                      -borderwidth 1 \
                      -labelborderwidth 1 \
                      -selectborderwidth 0 \
                      -xscrollcommand [list vmTkTools::configSB "h" $pfd(klaff_scrx)]\
                      -yscrollcommand [list vmTkTools::configSB "v" $pfd(klaff_scry)]]
```

Both tablelist have Bindings:

```
set body [$pfd(tali_mw) bodypath]
bind $body <Button-1> +[::itcl::code $this klickZeile %x %y %W]
bind $body <Double-1> +[::itcl::code $this doubleKlickMesswerte %x %y %W]

set body [$pfd(tali_klaff) bodypath]
bind $body <Button-1> [::itcl::code $this klickZeile %x %y %W]
```

The method klickZeile looks like this

```
itcl::body vmMaskHelmert::klickZeile {x y W} {
   puts "klickZeile"

   delCommonKreuz

   foreach {pfad xC yC} [tablelist::convEventFields $W $x $y] {}
   set row    [$pfad containing $yC]
   if {$row == -1} {
      set row end
   }

   if {[string first "tali_mw" $W] != -1} {
      # select the row
      $pfd(tali_mw) activate $row
      $pfd(tali_mw) selection clear 0 end
      $pfd(tali_mw) selection set $row $row
      anzeigePpMp
   } else {
      $pfd(tali_klaff) activate $row
      $pfd(tali_klaff) selection clear 0 end
      $pfd(tali_klaff) selection set $row $row
      anzeigePpMp4Klaff
   }
   return
}
```

It seems, that the method klickZeile blocks my double click binding, the method doubleKlickMesswerte is not being called.

In klickZeile two corresponding rows in both tablelists are selected.

I tried to comment out the two blocks with "activate $row, selection clear 0 end and selection set $row $row". In that case, doubleKlickMesswerte is being called but unfortunately the method klickZeile doesn't work correctly. It seems that in that case the method selects the corresponding row for the row selected before.

So I've got two questions:

How can I prevent the method klickZeile from blocking the double click binding? 
Or, if there is no way for this, what can I do, to make the method "klickZeile" work correctly without extra selection and activation?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Mouse click events (at least single/double/triple) without modifiers (like Control) will all trigger when a bind to triple is set up and the user triple-clicks on the target element. The GUI cannot predict that another click is coming. It has to dispatch the single-click event first, followed by the double, then the triple.

Your best alternative is to use a modifier, such as a , because this is unique and does not depend on sequence, as long as the Control button is pressed first ;)

```
proc doClick { widget } {
    puts "You clicked [$widget cget -text]"
}

proc doControlClick { widget } {
    puts "You control-clicked [$widget cget -text]"
}

set label_1 [label .l1 -text "This is label 1"]
pack $label_1 -side top -fill both


bind $label_1 <Control-Button-1> { doControlClick %W }
bind $label_1 <Button-1> { doClick %W }
```